# Need update from droid 11 to droid 12 NITRO8S

Tags: initialization, flash-builder, tablet, android-12

Unsure exactly which base device is mine in order to download correct version suits device. 2ANIRNITRO8S
DEVICE ALSO known as nitro8s

I've loaded emulator and am searching for correct version 12 to download, I'm attempting to update from 11 while still using device. Ive loaded emulator on flash. I plan to note my devices needed drivers and type of hardware. Am I forgetting anything I need to remember? And I'm on a 7 1/2" tablet nitro8 does a phone version of Android 12 adequate?